# Were there public events for sports and recreation which were followed in Ancient India?

Tags: mahabharata, ramayana, itihasa

In both Ramayan and Mahabharath, there are references to marriage alliance being made through tests of skill. If so, were there public events like the Olympics or World Cups of today which were specifically designed for display of skill and challenging others in tests of skills?

Comment: The "Ashwamedha Yaga" is one such test or Olympics-like event. There were games like Pachisi and Chaturangam in the Treta Yugam as well, as mentioned in the Mahabharatam.

Comment: @Aravind post that as an answer with sources.

Comment: In [Mahabharata, Adi Parva](https://www.sacred-texts.com/hin/m01/m01137.htm), after Pandavas and Kauravas complete their training, Drona announces a proficiency test: "Drona, ..., addressed king Dhritarashtra, in the presence of Kripa, Somadatta, Valhika, the wise son of Ganga (Bhishma), Vyasa, and Vidura, and said, 'O best of Kuru kings, thy children have completed their education. With thy permission, O king, let them now show their proficiency..."

Comment: I get that there were events that qualified as “graduation” for the kids. And the “Ashwamedha Yaga” I thought was when a king wanted to conquer land in a peaceful manner. I was wondering if there were predetermined events at regular intervals: annual fest or something like that which aspiring sportsmen can participate in.